# Spark speed up multiple join operations

Tags: database, performance, join, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose I have a rule like this:
p(v3,v4) :- t1(k1,v1), t2(k1,v2), t3(v1,v3), t4(v2,v4).

The task is join t1, t2, t3, and t4 together to produce a relation p.

Suppose t1, t2, t3, and t4 are already having same partitioner for their keys.

A common strategy is to join relations one by one, but it will force at least 3 shuffle/repartition operations. Details are below(suppose I have 10 partitions).

```py
1.join: x = t1.join(t2)
2.repartition: x = x.map(lambda (k1, (v1,v2)): (v1,v2)).partitionBy(10)
3.join: x = x.join(t3)
4.repartition: x = x.map(lambda (v1, (v2,v3)): (v2,v3)).partitionBy(10)
5.join: x = x.join(t4)
6.repartition: x = x.map(lambda (v2, (v3,v4)): (v3,v4)).partitionBy(10)
```

Because t1 to t4 all have same partitioner, and I repartition the intermediate result after every join, each join operations will not involve any shuffle.

However, the intermediate result(i.e. variable x) is huge in my practical code, 3 shuffle operations are still too many for me.

My questions are:

1. Is there anything wrong with my strategy to evaluate this rule? Is there any better, more efficient solution?
2. My understanding of shuffle operation is that, for each partition, Spark will do repartition independently, it will generate repartition results for each partition on disk(so-called shuffle write). Then, for each partition, Spark will get new repartition results from disk(so-called shuffle read). If my understanding is correct, each shuffle/repartition will always cost disk read and write. It's kind of a waste, if I can guarantee my memory is huge enough to store all data. Just as said in http://www.trongkhoanguyen.com/2015/04/understand-shuffle-component-in-spark.html. Is there any workaround to disable this kind of shuffle write and read operations? I think my program's performance bottleneck is due to shuffle IO overhead.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually network IO is the slower part out of two but if you're concerned you can always use local in-memory file system.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Below is what I do to follow your advice. 1.After typing "df", I found there is one tmpfs in my system, mounted on "/dev/shm", which has around 100G. 2.I set "spark.local.dir" to "/dev/shm", which should be the directory of shuffle write and read. When I run my program, I found out the used size of that tmpfs is changing from 0 to 3G, which far less than 100G. However, there is no speed up for my program.

Comment: Sorry for split, due to space constrain. But my program is still very slow. I wonder why I change the "spark.local.dir" from a regular file system to in-memory file system, there is no any speed up, even though the temporary file's size is 3G. Is tmpfs working properly, or is there anything else I am doing wrong?